# System.Data.SqlClient Transactions and Error Handling Support

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm trying to create multiple Stored Procedures, Functions and Tables against a MSSQL database programmatically.

I'm doing this via the `System.Data.SqlClient` library, **not** the `Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo` library. However whenever I use a script with a `transaction` or `try - catch` block, I get an incorrect syntax error message, yet when I run the script directly against the database (via Management Studio) it works fine.

An example of such script can be found below:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [Mobile].M_CreateOrder (@OrderName varchar(255),@DELDATE DATETIME, @DELQTY INT, @PRODID INT, @CUSTID INT)    
AS BEGIN    
BEGIN TRY    
BEGIN TRANSACTION    
DECLARE @DATE DATETIME = GETDATE(), @SUCCESS INT = 0    
DECLARE @ORDERID INT = (SELECT MAX(ORDER_ID) + 1 FROM ORDERS)    
INSERT INTO [dbo].[ORDERS]    
            (     
             [ORDER_ID]    
            ,[ORDER_NAME]    
            ,[PRODUCT_ID]    
            ,[CUSTOMER_ID]    
           )    
        VALUES    
            (    
             @ORDERID    
            ,@OrderName    
            ,@PRODID    
            ,@CUSTID    
            )    
            COMMIT TRAN    
            SET @SUCCESS = 1    
            END TRY    
            BEGIN CATCH    
                INSERT INTO Mobile.M_LOG (ENTRY_DATE, ENTRY_MESSAGE) VALUES (GETDATE(), ERROR_MESSAGE())    
                IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0    
                ROLLBACK TRAN    
            END CATCH    
            --Enter the row in the delivery column    
            BEGIN TRY    
            IF(@SUCCESS = 1)    
                BEGIN    
                EXEC M_CreateDelivery @ORDERID, @DELDATE, @DELQTY    
                END    
            END TRY    
            BEGIN CATCH    
                INSERT INTO Mobile.M_LOG (ENTRY_DATE, ENTRY_MESSAGE) VALUES (GETDATE(), ERROR_MESSAGE())    
                IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0    
                ROLLBACK TRAN    
            END CATCH    
END
```

Whenever this script is ran via `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()` I get the following error:

```
Exception Details: System.Exception: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Incorrect syntax near 'CATCH'.
  at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
  at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
  at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
  at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
  at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
  at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
  at SQL.NonQuery.Execute() in D:\Users\Blake\Documents\GitHub\SQL\NonQuery.cs:line 23
```

Is this down to using the `SqlClient` library instead of the `smo` library or is there something else that I've missed entirely?

If this is down to using the `SqlClient` library, are there any docs on what is and isn't supported? - The [ExecuteNonQuery MSDN Page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery(v=vs.110).aspx) doesn't list any explicit limitations, but does say the function can be used for performing these operations:

> You can use the ExecuteNonQuery to perform catalog operations (for
>   example, querying the structure of a database or creating database
>   objects such as tables).

Comment: Can you show the C# code showing how you load the text into the `SqlCommand`? There is no restriction like you are running into, my best guess is that you have a error in the C# code but we need to see it first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should of noticed this sooner... The problem was the comments.

As I was just adding a space to the end of each line and concatenating the strings together, everything after a line comment was being commented out.

Adding `\r\n` to the end of each line fixed the problem.